# Repeated AMQ9209/AMQ9999 in AMQERR01.LOG

Tags: ibm-mq

I see the following error message in AMQERR01.LOG on the mq server printed repeatedly

```
AMQ9209: Connection to host 'client-host (...)' for channel
'TEST_CHANNEL' closed.

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred receiving data from 'client-host (...)' over
TCP/IP.  The connection to the remote host has unexpectedly terminated.

The channel name is 'TEST_CHANNEL'; in some cases it cannot be determined and
so is shown as '????'.
```

followed by:

```
AMQ9999: Channel 'TEST_CHANNEL' to host 'client-host (...)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 5022 for channel 'TEST_CHANNEL'
ended abnormally. The host name is 'client-host (...)'; in some
cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
```

In the Action of the second message it says "Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage""

Why does this occur? Is this normal to have these errors and can these be suppressed as suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message usually indicates that an application has terminated without first closing the channel.  Occasionally it indicates that a firewall or other stateful network inspection has terminated the socket after a period of inactivity.

The correct answer in the first case is to change the applications to properly manage connections.  In the second case, upgrading to the latest client and server and using the new client channel tuning can prevent network timeouts on idle channels.

The ability to suppress specific error messages is for those who are unable to address the root causes of these problems.  As long as you aren't losing MQ messages, suppressing these errors increases the signal-to-noise ratio in the error logs.  However, this is only considered a temporary measure and if you need to debug something you may need to re-enable the suppressed errors.